# How to filter an ordered dictionary in Python using Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Actully I am new to Python.Working with Python,Django and Mysql.
I was trying to filter some data from an ordered dictionary which i received while fetching data from mySQL database.The entire data is there in a variable. But I want to store some of it in another variable...

This is my view.py file...

```
all_dataobj=fetchdata.objects.all()
pserializer=fetchdataSerializers(all_dataobj,many=True)
p = pserializer.data
print(p)
```

And I am getting data like this...

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('first_name', 'raunak'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'ron')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('first_name', 'josh'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'mod')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('first_name', 'david'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'cop')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 4), ('first_name', 'bob'), ('middle_name', 'zj'), ('last_name', 'go')])]
```

Now I want to filtre this ordered dictionary and store data of id 1 and 2 only in a variable.
So, if I print the result variable it should look like this...

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('first_name', 'raunak'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'ron')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('first_name', 'josh'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'mod')])]
```

Please help me...i am stuck for very long...How can I get so??

Comment: for y in pserializer.data:
       y = x["id"]    ..................................I did this to fetch the id s....the i wrote if y <2...but it didnt work...please help....

Comment: Add that to the question @RounakModak Also check if my answer below makes sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and choose only the `id`'s you want

```
ids_to_get = [1, 2]
#Loop over the list and select only the id's you want
res = [item for item in li if item.get('id') in ids_to_get]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('first_name', 'raunak'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'ron')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('first_name', 'josh'), ('middle_name', 'yy'), ('last_name', 'mod')])]
```

If a range of id's need to be looked into, say 1 to 100 inclusive of both limits, a conditional statement can be used

```
res = [item for item in li if 1 <= item.get('id') <= 100]
```

Comment: Thank You for the response...I am checking it out...Then replying...@Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: Thanks a lottttttt....It really did work....now please can you tell me just one more thing...it is related to this question only...in place of ............."ids_to_get = [1, 2]".............what can i add to select a range of data instead of 2 datas.....like i wanna get data from id 1 to 100...so what should i add instead of [1,2]???@devesh kumar

Comment: thanks a lottttt for the help....it really did work....my problem is totally solved...will be in touch if i face any further issues...thanks.@devesh kumar. :) :)

Comment: there is one more confusion...i want to add the condition "<= 100 && > 200"....in place of ....."res = [item for item in li if 1 <= item.get('id') <= 100]".......so i did like this......." res1 = [item for item in pserializer.data if 1 <= item.get('id') > 10 & if 1 <= item.get('id') <= 15 ] ".............but its not working....can you please help me out???@devesh kumar

Comment: thanks a lotttt..it worked..yes i know i should study first...actully i just started python 2 days back...i am studying from w3school...can you suggest me some good source to learn python along with django..@devesh kumar

Comment: thanks a lott for the suggestion ...actully I was using this code to fetch data from mysql and then breaking it into three variables and then write it to excel sheet...it is working fine with less data...but as i am using it for bulk data(2500000 data)...its not working...its taking lot of time...can you help?any suggestion about what i should do????@devesh kumar

Comment: ok ok thank you ...i will contact you if i face further issues...@devesh kumar